# How do I solve this divisibility problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

> **Question 23:** Which one of following statements holds true if and only if $n$ is a prime number?
> $$
> \begin{alignat}{2}
> &\text{(A)} &\quad n|(n-1)!+1 \\ 
> &\text{(B)} &\quad n|(n-1)!-1 \\
> &\text{(C)} &\quad n|(n+1)!-1 \\ 
> &\text{(D)} &\quad n|(n+1)!+1
> \end{alignat}
> $$

I ruled out choices C and D because $n$ is a natural factor of $(n+1)!$, so $n$ won't divide $n(n+1)! -1 $ or $n(n+1)!+1 $(that could be the case if $n$ is $1$ but this question concerns only primes). 
I would like to know how to choose between choices A and B. Alternative ways to approach the problem are equally welcome.

Comment: See [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

Comment: $(p-1) ! \cong -1 (mod \space p) $ . If you  want to prove, check the proof using symmetric group. It's very interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what is suggested in the other answer, it is better to gain at least a basic understanding of the material.

This is [Wilson's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WilsonsTheorem.html), which states that if $p$ is a prime number, then $(p-1)!\equiv-1\bmod p$.

For $p=2$ or $p=3$, this is verified by direct computation. For larger $p$, every factor in $(p-1)!=1×2×3×...×(p-1)$ except $1$ and $p-1$ is paired with its multiplicative inverse which is another one of the factors. For instance, with $p=5$ the factor $2$ is paired with $3$; with $p=7$ we pair $2$ with $4$ and $3$ with $5$. These multiplicative-inverse pairs then each have product $1\bmod p$, so the factorial including all factors must be $(p-1)\equiv-1\bmod p$.

Thus (a).

Answer (score 6):

Given that it's a multiple choice question, and you're not required to present an actual proof, you can proceed by elimination. Which of the following are true:

3|2!+1
3|2!-1
3|4!+1
3|4!-1